# C Struggling with packing unsigned ints into uint64_t

Tags: c, math, bit-manipulation, packing, uint64

I am given a collection of data and I am required to pack it into a uint64_t value, which in the following example takes the form of type "weatherlog_t"

I am not allowed to use arithmetic operators (+, ++, -, --, *, %, /, ...), I am allowed however to use bitwise operators (&, |, ^, <<, >>, ~) and logical operators (!, =, --, !=, &&, and ||)

I do however have predefined add() and sub() functions that handle bitwise addition and subtraction, and they are used in the following example. These have been tested and I'm fairly sure they work to the degree needed here.

According to the instructions, the 64-bit value must be arranged as follows:

```
    /* - year :: 6 bits -- stored as the number of years since the year 2000.
    - month :: 4 bits
    - day :: 5 bits
    - zip_code :: 16 bits
    - high_temp :: in degrees Fahrenheit, stored as an 8-bit signed integer
    - low_temp :: in degrees Fahrenheit, stored as 8-bit signed integer
    - precipitation :: in mm. stored as a 10-bit unsigned integer.
    - average_wind_speed :: 7 bits. unsigned int km/hr.

    All of these are packed into a 64 bit unsigned integer in the above order.

    We'd store:
- year :: 2015, which is 15 years from 2000, so 001111
- month :: September, which is the 9th month, so 1001.
- day :: 16, which is 1 0000
- zip_code :: 19122 which is 0100 1010 1011 0010
- high_temp :: 85F, so 0101 0101
- low_temp :: 65F, so 0100 0001
- precipitation :: 35 mm so 00 0010 0011
- average wind speed :: 5 km/h, so 000 0101

And all would be packed into a single 64-bit unsigned integer:

00 1111 1001 10000 0100 1010 1011 0010 0101 0101 0100 0001 00 0010 0011 000 0101

OR

0011 1110 0110 0000 1001 0101 0110 0100 1010 1010 1000 0010 0001 0001 1000 0101 */
```

So far, what I have is:

```
weatherlog_t pack_log_entry(unsigned int year, unsigned int month, unsigned int day,
                        unsigned int zip, int high_temp, int low_temp,
                        unsigned int precip, unsigned int avg_wind_speed) {


weatherlog_t ret = 0;

unsigned int newYear = sub(year, 2000);

ret = (ret << 6);
ret = add(ret, newYear);

ret = (ret << 4);
ret = add(ret, month);

ret = (ret << 5);
ret = add(ret, day);

ret = (ret << 16);
ret = add(ret, zip);

ret = (ret << 8);
ret = add(ret, high_temp);

ret = (ret << 8);
ret = add(ret, low_temp);

ret = (ret << 10);
ret = add(ret, precip);

ret = (ret << 6);
ret = add(ret, avg_wind_speed);


return ret;
}
```

However, when I go in and test this, checking the binary value of ret, it seems to stop at 32-bits, and shifting left after this point causes any bits left of the 32nd leftmost bit to be lost. I am struggling to understand what I am doing wrong, although I am new at bitwise arithmetic and do not fully understand as of yet how it interacts with the C language.

EDIT: As requested, code for add() and subtract()

```
unsigned int add(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) {
/* can be done in a total of 7 lines, including one to declare an unsigned int, */
/* two for a while loop, and one for the return
 You're not required to do it in 7 lines though . */
while(j != 0){
    unsigned int carry = i & j;

    i = i ^ j;

    j = carry << 1;
}

return i;
}


unsigned int sub(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) {
/* Similar 7 lines, although there is a shorter way */
while (j != 0){
    unsigned int borrow = (~i) & j;

    i = i ^ j;

    j = borrow << 1;
}

return i;
}
```

Comment: Show the declaration of `weatherlog_t`.

Comment: `typedef uint64_t weatherlog_t;`

Comment: `add` and `subtract` are using `unsigned int` which may be only 32 bits.

Comment: Would redefining or defining new add() and sub() functions with return and parameter types of weatherlog_t alleviate this issue?

Comment: Concerning temperature: "degrees Fahrenheit, stored as an 8-bit signed integer".  Temps are known to range from [-129F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_temperature_recorded_on_Earth) to [134F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highest_temperature_recorded_on_Earth):  A range not quite handled by "8-bit signed integer".  Perhaps Celsius?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what you need those add/sub functions for; seems like obfuscation. Packing data in specific bits is much more straight-forward:

```
#define YEAR_POS  58
#define MONTH_POS 48

ret = (uint64_t)year  << YEAR_POS  |
      (uint64_t)month << MONTH_POS |
       ...
```

This have benefits of being 1) fast, and 2) endian-independent = fully portable.

You might have to mask each variable in advance if you suspect that they contain garbage beyond the specified sizes:

```
#define YEAR_SIZE 6
year &= (1u << YEAR_SIZE)-1;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Packing with shift+or is the conventional, faster, and cleaner solution.

Comment: Masking is not only for garbage.out-of-range values.  Masking needed for signed values.

Comment: @chux Well, if the input contains negative values, it is probably incorrect. Though of course we shouldn't use bitwise operators on negative values. Curiously though, the data in the question contains temperatures, which could possibly be expressed as two's complement negative. The spec is lacking here. (I envy those who never have to express outdoors temperature with negative numbers...)

Comment: "if the input contains negative values, it is probably incorrect." --> A low temp < 0F might be uncommon for some, yet not where you and I live.  I see white stuff out there now.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment due to my lack of reputation.

When you specifically need an integer value to have a certain signedness and width, you can use the types defined in `stdint.h`. From what I can tell that appears to be one of the issues, given add and substract return an unsigned integer and have it in their arguments - how wide they are is platform dependant. stdint.h guarantees signedness and width. Since you're using these two functions and add the result to a uint64_t, you may lose bytes in the progress.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Integers.html

If you cannot adjust the return value of add and sub, I would suggest making new ones specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your `add` and `sub` functions each take two argument of type `unsigned int` and return an `unsigned int`.  This type is most likely smaller than 64 bits, so passing a `uint64_t` to one of these functions truncates the value.

Change the parameter types to `weatherlog_t` as well as the locals used within the functions and the return types.

```
weatherlog_t add(weatherlog_t i, weatherlog_t j) {
    /* can be done in a total of 7 lines, including one to declare an unsigned int, */
    /* two for a while loop, and one for the return
     You're not required to do it in 7 lines though . */
    while(j != 0){
        weatherlog_t carry = i & j;

        i = i ^ j;

        j = carry << 1;
    }

    return i;
}

weatherlog_t sub(weatherlog_t i, weatherlog_t j) {
    /* Similar 7 lines, although there is a shorter way */
    while (j != 0){
        weatherlog_t borrow = (~i) & j;

        i = i ^ j;

        j = borrow << 1;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: I do not believe I am permitted to change the parameters of pack_log_entry. Would casting them to weatherlog_t do the job?

Comment: @MattAngelucci It will not, as the type of the arguments will only hold 32 bits.  If these functions were supplied by your professor, you need to go back to him and explain they are faulty.

Comment: It's possible the add and sub functions were only intended to be used on the individual values, and not on the 64 bits pack.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

Code is failing to mask upper bits of signed values like `high_temp`.

Last shift is curiously 6 and not 7.

Pedantic, code fails to insure augments are in range.  Another reason to mask to limit out-of-range value form affecting other fields.

"it seems to stop at 32-bits" due to `add()` limited to 32-bits [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53226547/2410359).  `add()` not needed anyways.

---

Simply *shift* , *mask*, *or*.

```
#define N_YEAR 6
#define N_MONTH 4
#define N_DAY 5
#define N_ZIP 16
#define N_HTEMP 8
#define N_LTEMP 8
#define N_PREC 10
#define N_AWS 7
#define MSK(bw) ((1u << (bw)) - 1)

weatherlog_t pack_log_entry(unsigned int year, unsigned int month,
    unsigned int day, unsigned int zip, int high_temp, int low_temp,
    unsigned int precip, unsigned int avg_wind_speed) {

  weatherlog_t ret = 0;
  ret = (ret << N_YEAR)  | (sub(year, 2000) & MSK(N_YEAR));
  ret = (ret << N_MONTH) | (month           & MSK(N_MONTH));
  ret = (ret << N_DAY)   | (day             & MSK(N_DAY));
  //... others
  ret = (ret << N_PREC)  | (precip          & MSK(N_PREC)) ;
  ret = (ret << N_AWS)   | (avg_wind_speed  & MSK(N_AWS));
  return ret;
}
```